# Warning received at QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase, when running inspect code using PyCharm on python and Qt

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt4

I'm building a desktop app in python 2.7 and I'm making the GUI in PyQt4. I'm using PyCharm and when I run the inspect code I get a warning message.  "Passing str instead of PyQt4.QtSql.QSqlDatabase. Is this intentional?".
  My code looks like this:

```
self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
self.db.setHostName("localhost")
self.db.setDatabaseName("templateDb.db")
self.db.open()
```

The warning appears to the first line and it's about this string `"QSQLITE"`.

The app is working ok, no problems with that. But I'm curious if it's a PyCharm problem or there is another way to write the first line?

Thank you.

Comment: It's definitely a pycharm problem. Obviously if you run the same code in a console, there will be no warnings. There are no overloads of [addDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsqldatabase.html#static-public-members) which take a QSqlDatabase object.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your database name into QString. 
"addDatabase" function takes an argument as Qstring not in string format.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
a = QString("QSQLITE")
self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase(a)
```

I am not sure this will work or not. But try this.

Comment: Now I got, **expected `QSqlDatabase`, got `QString` instead.**. Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes Pycharm gives such types of waring messages. In pyqt there are multiple syntax available for same thing, where in Pycharm don't support all of them. So you can ignore such warning messages or set filter for this type of warnings to your Prcharm configuration.